What is the geometric explanation for why the shape operator is symmetric?
The shape operator at acts on the tangent space of a manifold at $p$:
$S_p: T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$
By:
$$S_p(v) = D_v(n(p))$$
That is, it sends the normal vector at $p$ to it's directional derivative in the direction of the input vector. The proof that this map is symmetric follows easily from the fact that partial derivatives commute, but I was hoping that somebody here could tell me why the geometric reason why this map is symmetric w.r.t. an inner product on the tangent space:
$$S_p(V) \cdot U = V \cdot S_p(U)$$
The eigenvalues of this map are the principle curvatures and the direction of the eigenvectors are the principle directions.

I don’t really have a good answer, but the reason why the second fundamental form is symmetric (and hence why the shape operator is self-adjoint) is because the connection being used (Levi-Civita) is torsion-free. Btw, it’s not quite what you said but having a torsion-free connection is equivalent to the second covariant derivatives of functions being symmetric (i.e Hessian of functions being symmetric), not just mixed partials being equal. Anyway, I don’t have a very good geometric explanation to tie it all together to explain why the vanishing of torsion implies symmetry of the 2nd FF.

partly because legitimately visualizing torsion itself is a challenge for me…

Perhaps a geometric explanation comes from considering the osculating quadric surface to the surface at the point. So can we see it “geometrically” in that case?

Here is a way to describe @TedShifrin's answer: You can assume that $p$ is the origin and $T_pM$ is the hyperplane $x^n=0$. In that case, $M$ near $p$ is the graph of a function $f$, i.e., $$ M = { (x^1, \dots, x^{n-1}, f(x^1, \dots, x^{n-1}) } \subset \mathbb{R}^n. $$ $M$ is well approximated at $p$ by the quadric hypersurface
$$
x^n = \frac{1}{2}h_{ij}x^ix^j,
$$
where $h_{ij} = \partial^2_{ij}f(0).$
That partials commute implies that $h_{ij}=h_{ji}$. The second fundamental form at $p$, with respect to the coordinates $(x^1,\dots, x^{n-1})$ is given by this symmetric matrix.

@TedShifrin Thank you so much for the great differential geometry notes! The exercises are so challenging, If you know of any solution guide available I'd appreciate it! Peace

No solutions available, but you’ll find a number of the more challenging questions discussed on this very site.  (There are plenty of standard questions in the notes, too, you know. And I assume you know that there are some answers/solutions at the back.)
